# Regex OR pipe not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to match multiple regular expressions in a single regular expression.

Given two extremely complex regular expressions, how could I keep them separate, yet put them into a single expression which matches both. I thought that was the use of the regex OR pipe, but it seems to not be working as I expected.

As a basic example, I'm working with the following regular expression:

```
(?:\s*(\w+)\s*:)|(?:\:\s*(\w+)\s*\,)
```

Testing with the following string:

```
{key: value, name: "John", age: 17}
```

And expecting it to capture in the two `(\w+)` capture groups:

`key`, `value`, `name` **and** `age`

But it is only capturing `key`, `name` and `age` **without** the `value`.

I can confirm the 2nd part of my expression *(after the OR pipe)* does indeed match the `value` when the first part of the expression is omitted *(before the OR pipe)*.

---

Can someone please explain and provide a solution as to why it is not matching both `key` and `value` and only matching `key`.

Comment: Why not [`(\w+):\s*(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/meETbN/2)?

Comment: Maybe this could work in some cases, but the expression I'm working with is actually a little more complex, I simplified for the sake of the question.

Comment: It would be much better if you described a real life case/scenario with a more real life sample

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've edited my answer to my real regex.

Comment: Try [`\w+(?=\s*[,:])`](https://regex101.com/r/meETbN/5/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're attempting to merge the two expressions *before* and *after* the OR pipe, correct? What happens if the expression is a whole lot more complicated, I'm just curious how this could be solved. I assume it cannot always be 'merged'

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are capturing : in both groups so the | can't match both

This should work

```
(?:\s*(\w+)\s*:)|(?:\s*(\w+)\s*\,)
```

[Regex101 live example](https://regex101.com/r/9EiCmr/2)

Comment: This doesn't quite match the results I was looking for. I wasn't wanting to match `"John"` or `17`. But you still made use of the `OR` pipe. In my expression, something causes the OR pipe to not work :/

Answer (score 1):

> In my expression, something causes the OR pipe to not work :/
>
> Can someone please explain …

Actually, with "you are capturing : in both groups so the | can't match both" KinSlayerUY did explain why, in your view, *something causes the OR pipe to not work*. In other words: Since the alternative to the left of `|` already contained the `:` after `key`, there was no `:` available to match the alternative to the right with `: value,` (remember that matches don't overlap).